# Is it necessary to assign a default value in model field?

Tags: python, django, database, model-view-controller

As I know in Django, it requires the user to determine the default
value for models fields. Like:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    """Student info"""
    id = models.CharField( max_length=7,primary_key=True,default =-1)
    name = models.CharField(_('name'),max_length=8, default="x");
```

But I'm really annoyed at this. I just don't know what values have to be assgind in the first place. User should make the decision.

Can I just

1. Give None as the default value? What might be consequences? NPE?
2. Give a random value.

Is it specific to give a default value to the model field in Django?
Or it's general to most MVC web frameworks.
Or it's because of the database consideration?
Thanks

Comment: It is for migration purpose.

Answer (score 1):

`null=True` and `blank=True` are two different things and shouldn't be mixed up.

In order not to have a default field in your model attribute you just need `null=True`, which basically means "I'm ok with this column storing null values'.

`blank=True` means that when that attribute appears in a `ModelForm` it will render the corresponding field as `required`. Basically it's about **form validation**.

This might seem like an edge case, especially since a lot of people prefer to write their own forms rather than using Django `ModelForm` but you know what else uses the `ModelForm`? The django admin.

Yeah, so unless you want to have that field `required` also in the django admin then you should add `blank=True` to your model attribute.

But having `blank=True` is not going to affect whether you need or not a default value.

Comment: I think blank = True means it's not required in ModelForm.

Answer (score 0):

you can set `null=True, blank=True` if you dont want that field to be mandatory.

Comment: It's bothering. I add two attributes to just skip one attribute.

Comment: you can set `default value` or `null=True, blank=True` or assign values to every field while creating obj. Choice is yours

Comment: `null=True` is usually a bad idea for a CharField. Reserve it for relations. Normally just `blank=True`  and `default=''` suffices. A form will display the field blank and validate OK if the user sends it back still blank. Or not, if you make that fail validation. Having to check for None values complicates the code and often leads to bugs.

Comment: @nigel222 Yes, totally correect. When null=True, blank=True and '' empty string both satisfy the condition.

Answer (score 0):

If the fields are not mandatory (can be left empty) then you can make them nullable by using `null=True`. Note that for char fields it is the better practice to use `blank=True` instead.

For the second thing you mentioned, it is possible to pass a callable to the model field as the default value. So, you can write a function which generates random values and pass that as the field's default value.